# Copiar o conteúdo de uma planilha e colar em uma nova utilizando VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Boa tarde!

Preciso criar um código em VBA que copie o conteúdo de várias planilhas e cole em uma planilha especifica. No caso, teria que ter um laço de repetição para abrir as planilhas de um diretório, copiar e colar em uma única planilha final. Vocês podem me ajudar?

Desde já agradeço!

Answer (score 1):

Vinicio Lima, boa tarde.

Para esse código funcionar corretamente você deve deixar as varias planilhas(pastas de trabalho) e a planilha especifica(pasta de trabalho) de destino no mesmo diretório.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Execute a sub 'transferenciaDeDados'. Deixei como exemplo uma simples transferência de dados das demais planilhas para a planilha destino.

**Segue o código, espero ter ajudado.**

```
Sub transferenciaDeDados()
    transfere_dados
End Sub

Private Function transfere_dados()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim arquivos() As Variant
    Dim caminho As String
    Dim pastaDeTrabalho As String
    Dim pastaDeTrabalhoAtiva As String
    Dim linhaDeInicio As long
    caminho = ActiveWorkbook.Path
    arquivos = listfiles(caminho)
    pastaDeTrabalhoAtiva = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    linhaDeInicio = 1
    'verificação de arquivos
    For Each arquivo In arquivos
        'executa somente se para extenção .xlsx
        If InStr(1, arquivo, ".xlsx") <> 0 And _
            InStr(1, arquivo, "~$") = 0 Then
            pastaDeTrabalho = caminho & "\" & arquivo
            'abre pasta de trabalho
            Workbooks.Open (pastaDeTrabalho)

            'Sua lógica aqui
            'copia valores da célula A1 da primeira planilha da pasta de trabalho aberta
            'em sequência na coluna A da primeira planilha da psta de trabalho de destino, ativa.

            Workbooks(pastaDeTrabalhoAtiva).Sheets(1).Range("A" & linhaDeInicio).Value = _
                Workbooks(arquivo).Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value

            'fecha pasta de trabalho
            Workbooks(arquivo).Close
            linhaDeInicio = linhaDeInicio + 1
        End If
        pastaDeTrabalho = ""
    Next
    pastaDeTrabalhoAtiva = ""
    linhaDeInicio = 0
End Function

Function listfiles(ByVal sPath As String)

    Dim vaArray     As Variant
    Dim i           As long
    Dim oFile       As Object
    Dim oFSO        As Object
    Dim oFolder     As Object
    Dim oFiles      As Object

    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(sPath)
    Set oFiles = oFolder.Files

    If oFiles.Count = 0 Then Exit Function

    ReDim vaArray(1 To oFiles.Count)
    i = 1
    For Each oFile In oFiles
        vaArray(i) = oFile.Name
        i = i + 1
    Next

    listfiles = vaArray

End Function
```

Comment: Paulo, é recomendado a declaração como `Long`. Por inúmeros motivos, mas leia [esta resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26409520/7690982) e entenda a razão. Pois em computadores modernos, este ganho de memória não é significante, podendo até utilizar a mesma memória de um Long em sistemas 32 bits. Já os possíveis erros são inúmeros...

Comment: Daniel, tem razão obrigado.